# How do I return the snapshot value of my Firebase Realtime Database from a function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to return the `snapshot.val()`, of my Realtime Database:

```
function get_details(){
   get(ref(db,"pay/0/0/")).then((snapshot) => {
       if (snapshot.exists()) {
           var resp = [];
           resp.push(snapshot.val());
           return resp;
       }
   }
}

let response = get_details();
console.log(response); //undefined
```

I keep getting `undefined` as the returned value. I have followed the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71722860/20990866) post.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling `get_details` from somewhere else in the code. Try:

```
async function get_details() {
  const snapshot = await get(ref(db, "pay/0/0/"))
  return snapshot.val()
}

// get_details() also returns a Promise.
get_details().then((response) => {
  // continue
  console.log('Value is', response)
})


// Alternatively, if parent function is async

const mainFunc = async () => {
  const response = await get_details()
}
```

Also checkout [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)